# Missing members in custom progressbar

Tags: vb.net, winforms, progress-bar

I am new in this field and I find myself in difficulty, I have already looked for two days on the internet and I have not found anything or at least that is understandable within my reach.
I downloaded a file for a new ProgressBar in 3d, but I no longer have the option of [Step] and [PerformStep], how can I add these two properties?
Please help me, I've been running after it for days....

I downloaded a file from this post https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d3eee65-730b-488f-a858-a341b8d61714/progressbar-with-percentage-label?forum=vbgeneral at the bottom of the page the link for RmCustProgressBar but I have problems.
Here The file for download is file txt https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ADU6srhRub2eM6M&cid=00D11ED12923BE81&id=D11ED12923BE81%21114&parId=root&o=OneUp

```
Public Sub righeNere()
    Dim row_count As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count
    RmCustProgressBar1.MaxValue = row_count
    RmCustProgressBar1.Step = 1
    Dim currencyManager1 As CurrencyManager = CType(DataGridView1.BindingContext(DataGridView1.DataSource), CurrencyManager)
    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If rw.Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Gold Or rw.Cells(3).Style.BackColor = Color.Gold Or rw.Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.Gold Or rw.Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Gold Or rw.Cells(6).Style.BackColor = Color.Gold Or rw.Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.Gold Then
            rw.Visible = True
            Continue For
        ElseIf rw.Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.White Or rw.Cells(3).Style.BackColor = Color.White Or rw.Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.White Or rw.Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.White Or rw.Cells(6).Style.BackColor = Color.White Or rw.Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.White Then
            currencyManager1.SuspendBinding()
            rw.Visible = False
            currencyManager1.ResumeBinding()
            RmCustProgressBar1.PerformStep()
        End If
    Next
End Subd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `Step` is a step size and that `PerformStep` simply adds this step to the `Value` property. Then you can add this functionality like this in the progress bar class:

```vb
Public Property [Step] As Integer

Public Sub PerformStep()
    Value = Math.Min(MaxValue, Value + [Step])

    'To refresh the progress bar immediately (optional)
    Refresh()
End Sub
```

Setting the `Value` property invalidates the control, i.e. the new progress bar position will be displayed automatically, but maybe with some delay. If you want to refresh it immediately, you can force a redraw by calling `Refresh()`. See: [Control.Refresh Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.refresh)

Note that `Step` is a reserved word in VB, therefore we must put it in angle brackets. Instead, we could also call it `StepSize`.

Comment: Thanks for the help and support, I entered the codes in the ProgressBar class and now it accepts me [Step] and [PerformStep] without errors, the only problem is that it stops at 90% and does not do the job once finished immediately arrives 100% on the bar, while if I use a system ProgressBar I can see the percentage progress until the job is done and finished. What can I do?

Comment: You can call [Refresh()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.refresh). See my updated code.